# Use Qt Remote Objects in Visual Studio (with qt plugin)

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qtremoteobjects

I want to develop a program using Visual Studio working with Qt Remote Objects but I don't find the correct way to have it working. Based to [this log](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/tree/Changelog?id=v2.4.0) the Qt Visual Studio Tools should support Qt Remote Objects managements starting from version 2.4.0. However I don't understand in which field of project Qt settings insert the REPC_SOURCE value. Someone can give me the correct tips?

Comment: What version Qt do you have?

Comment: Qt Visual Studio Tools version 2.7.1 rev 18 and Qt version 5.15.2 (Visual Studio Community 2019)

Comment: I recommend you to use qt creator IDE, it's much easier and interesting than visual studio.

Comment: This is your opinion, I think completely opposite. Qt Creator is a good tool but Visual Studio is awesome. By the way the topic is not which IDE is the best.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to my own request for all is interested the Qt Remote Objects field in project settings show up only if a .rep file is added to the project.